# Relationship between IIS App Pool and Oracle Pooling Ado.Net

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net

What is the relationship between the Worker Process from IIS App Pool (Windows Server 2012 R2) and Oracle 11g Pooling?
I have an X application written in C# Framework 4.0, configured with an AppPool first with a Max Worker Process 1 and then I change to 4.

My connection string is:
Data Source = EXAMPLE; User Id = YYYY; Password = BBB; Connect Timeout = 30; Max Pool Size = 100; Pooling = true; Min Pool Size = 5; Incr Pool Size = 5; Decr Pool Size = 2; Connection Lifetime = 300

Having pooling in true, I now that I have 1 Worker Process, the total Max Pool Size is 100. The question is, if I upload Worker Process to 4, the maximum total of Max Pool Size is 400 or it stays at 100? (I read this here https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/4340018 )

The above is because I have read that the orchestrator is the connection string, so if the string is repeated, it is reused in the Oracle Pooling, even if it is from another App Pool (IIS) the request that triggers it.

Other questions:

Who increases in 5 connections? (Incr Pool Size = 5) Ado.Net?
If I close the application, those 5 connections is removed from pool? or all pools?

Have I read that every 3 minutes Ado.Net check the inactive connections of the Pooling? Is it like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please don't mix IIS Application pool and database connection pool such as Oracle connection pool.

IIS Application pool and Oracle connection pool are totally unrelated. IIS pool means how many connection IIS will have pool of application requests, and also to help isolate other web applications that use the same IIS. Therefore IIS worker process doesn't concern about how the app connect to any database server.

This is the official definition from [IIS Application pool documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/):

> An application pool defines a group of one or more worker processes, configured with common settings that serve requests to one or more applications that are assigned to that application pool. Because application pools allow a set of Web applications to share one or more similarly configured worker processes, they provide a convenient way to isolate a set of Web applications from other Web applications on the server computer.

This is totally different concept with Oracle connection pool. It is basically a common feature of any database server has, not specific to Oracle. It is basically how many concurrent database connection that the connection pool can handle, before it goes reached the limit of maximum allowed database connections to a single DB server, because different database servers may have its own limit set differently.

Comment: Thank, but in this post https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/4340018 says Open Sesions in Pool = Max Pool Size * Number of Worker Processes....then, there exists a relationship between Worker Process and Oracle Pool, or this is a mistake?

Comment: @HernaldoGonzalez No, the statement is wrong. DB connection pool _is always may be set and configured_ independent of the number of max connection pool limit, depends on what DB is used.Example: you can have large number of DB connections on a single worker process, and it is common in many ASP.NET or other web apps.